# Are users not already notified when an answer on their question is edited?

Tags: feature-request

See this sister question:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306419/people-should-get-notified-when-answers-to-their-questions-are-edited

I could have sworn this is already the case for CRSE but I don't remember.

Comment: Also related: [_Optional notification on an edit to an answer_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97740/341145) which is marked a duplicate of [_Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64692/341145) on Meta SE

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ That's strange, since it's marked `status-completed`.